# Converting two dicts into one dict as key value pair in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

lets say I am having two dictionaries:
`dictA = [1 : 7, 2 : 3, 3 : 4]` and `dictB = [1 : Car, 2 :Banana, 3 : Apple]`.

How is it possible to make a new dictionary like so: `dictAB =[Car : 7, Banana : 3, Apple : 4]`?

As you can see, I would like to make a new dictionary whereby for the same key in both dictionaries, a new key value pair is generated out of the two initial values and therefore the key from the dictionaries is kind of used as an index.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: You must have tried something? Please share your effort so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, determine the set of keys that are common to both dictionaries. Then, use those keys to assemble a new dictionary:

```
let dictA = [1 : 7, 2 : 3, 3 : 4]
let dictB = [1 : "Car", 2: "Banana", 3: "Apple"]
let dictAB = ["Car": 7, "Banana": 3, "Apple": 4]

let commonKeys = Set(dictA.keys).intersection(dictB.keys)
let temp = commonKeys.map { (dictB[$0]!, dictA[$0]!) }
let result = Dictionary(temp, uniquingKeysWith: {v1, v2 in v2} )

print(result) // ["Banana": 3, "Apple": 4, "Car": 7]
print(result == dictAB) // true
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
let dictAB = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: dictB.map { ($0.value, dictA[$0.key]) })
```